# How can I change the Account Type Checkbox from the Join Form in Oxwall to Radiobuttons?

Tags: join, oxwall

Where can I change the code to replace the chekboxes on the join form for the oxwall account types (looking for in skadate) so that I have radiobuttons? The user should be able only select one of the account types.

Comment: Selecting the account type in Oxwall  join page is a dropdown. Isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

Check on this path

```
systemplugins/base/contollers/join.php
```